# Why viewWillAppear is not called in my UITabBArController when i use presentModelViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, presentmodalviewcontroller

My app is a view based application. I made a login view and if user enters right username and password i go to main menu which is a UITabViewController like this:

```
 MainMenuController *mainMenu = [[[MainMenuController alloc] init] autorelease];
[mainMenu setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
[self presentModalViewController:mainMenu animated:YES];
```

mainMenu has 4 tabs with these names: Menu, History, Settings, Music.

when i click on tabs then viewWillAppear of view attached with that tab should be called. But its not calling viewWillAppear of any tab. In Menu tab i am generating a tableView when a button is clicked like this:

```
 [self presentModalViewController:sel animated:YES];
```

and when any row of the table is tapped i call this:

```
 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

so that table view goes away. Strange thing is after this is done, viewWillAppear is called for every view attached to tab bar. Then when i switch between tab bar views then viewWillAppear for every view is called. Why is that so and is there any way that viewWillAppear of every view attached with TabBarController will be called without calling new tableView? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you present your TabViewController modally?

Comment: i have to do some settings. every row of that tableview sets something. but the thing is viewWillAppear for every view attached with TabBarController is called when that table view is dismissed. Why are they not called before that tableView is presented and dismissed.

Comment: just forget about that tableView. I wrote about that because after present and dismiss of tableView, viewWillAppear of every view is called.

Answer (score 0):

You did not answered my question, but ok. Try this, put your menu tab as the second one. See if the `viewWillAppear` is called now.

Comment: i wrote about tableView just to tell that if i make a view like that then viewWillAppear is called for every view not. that tableView is created by a button in mainMenu view. I have 4 tabs.when i change between tabs, none of them call their viewWillAppear. just forget about tableView.

Comment: its not working. putting menu tab as second one gives the same result

Comment: So let me get this straight you have 4 tabs and the viewWillAppear is not called. But if you put a table in your first tab they are called?

Comment: yes. if that table view is appeared using [presentModalViewController:sel animated:YES] and dismisses using [dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]

Comment: Want a tip? Don't present the UITabBarController using a presentModalViewController.

Comment: its not navigation based application so i can't use navigational controller. is there any other way?